# Container cycles between healthy and died

Tags: docker, podman, alma-linux

I have added a container to my AlmaLinux 8 host and it starts fine (started as a service).  But I notice strange output in the log below.  Systemctl reports my service is running fine.

Is the below just normal output?  It says healthy in one line, and died on the next.  And this keeps repeating.

```
Sep 30 13:14:36 lserver systemd[1]: Started /usr/bin/podman healthcheck run aca8a5a216ea6cdacc27cac48aa7ba8da880534d7bd332b626a5a3cef7e85c57.
Sep 30 13:14:36 lserver systemd[1]: tmp-crun.y3qAWM.mount: Deactivated successfully.
Sep 30 13:14:36 lserver podman[9325]: 2023-09-30 13:14:36.661692833 -0400 EDT m=+0.097308147 container health_status aca8a5a216ea6cdacc27cac48aa7ba8da880534d7bd332b626a5a3cef7e85c57 (image=docker.io/jacobalberty/unifi:latest, name=unifi, health_status=healthy, ghcr.io/jacobalberty/unifi-docker:v7=, ghcr.io/jacobalberty/unifi-docker:v7.4=, jacobalberty/unifi:v7.4=, jacobalberty/unifi:v7.4.162=, maintainer=Jacob Alberty <jacob.alberty@foundigital.com>, ghcr.io/jacobalberty/unifi-docker:latest=, org.opencontainers.image.ref.name=ubuntu, org.opencontainers.image.version=18.04, ghcr.io/jacobalberty/unifi-docker:v7.4.162=, jacobalberty/unifi:latest=, jacobalberty/unifi:v7=)
Sep 30 13:14:36 lserver podman[9325]: 2023-09-30 13:14:36.724515206 -0400 EDT m=+0.160130482 container exec_died aca8a5a216ea6cdacc27cac48aa7ba8da880534d7bd332b626a5a3cef7e85c57 (image=docker.io/jacobalberty/unifi:latest, name=unifi, org.opencontainers.image.version=18.04, jacobalberty/unifi:v7.4=, org.opencontainers.image.ref.name=ubuntu, jacobalberty/unifi:v7=, ghcr.io/jacobalberty/unifi-docker:v7=, ghcr.io/jacobalberty/unifi-docker:v7.4.162=, ghcr.io/jacobalberty/unifi-docker:v7.4=, jacobalberty/unifi:latest=, jacobalberty/unifi:v7.4.162=, maintainer=Jacob Alberty <jacob.alberty@foundigital.com>, ghcr.io/jacobalberty/unifi-docker:latest=)
Sep 30 13:14:36 lserver systemd[1]: aca8a5a216ea6cdacc27cac48aa7ba8da880534d7bd332b626a5a3cef7e85c57.service: Deactivated successfully.
Sep 30 13:15:07 lserver systemd[1]: Started /usr/bin/podman healthcheck run aca8a5a216ea6cdacc27cac48aa7ba8da880534d7bd332b626a5a3cef7e85c57.
Sep 30 13:15:07 lserver systemd[1]: tmp-crun.dByCgB.mount: Deactivated successfully.
Sep 30 13:15:07 lserver podman[9360]: 2023-09-30 13:15:07.480932834 -0400 EDT m=+0.129300293 container health_status aca8a5a216ea6cdacc27cac48aa7ba8da880534d7bd332b626a5a3cef7e85c57 (image=docker.io/jacobalberty/unifi:latest, name=unifi, health_status=healthy, ghcr.io/jacobalberty/unifi-docker:v7.4=, jacobalberty/unifi:v7.4.162=, org.opencontainers.image.version=18.04, ghcr.io/jacobalberty/unifi-docker:v7.4.162=, jacobalberty/unifi:latest=, ghcr.io/jacobalberty/unifi-docker:latest=, ghcr.io/jacobalberty/unifi-docker:v7=, jacobalberty/unifi:v7.4=, maintainer=Jacob Alberty <jacob.alberty@foundigital.com>, jacobalberty/unifi:v7=, org.opencontainers.image.ref.name=ubuntu)
Sep 30 13:15:07 lserver podman[9360]: 2023-09-30 13:15:07.583246769 -0400 EDT m=+0.231614192 container exec_died aca8a5a216ea6cdacc27cac48aa7ba8da880534d7bd332b626a5a3cef7e85c57 (image=docker.io/jacobalberty/unifi:latest, name=unifi, maintainer=Jacob Alberty <jacob.alberty@foundigital.com>, ghcr.io/jacobalberty/unifi-docker:v7.4.162=, jacobalberty/unifi:latest=, ghcr.io/jacobalberty/unifi-docker:latest=, ghcr.io/jacobalberty/unifi-docker:v7=, ghcr.io/jacobalberty/unifi-docker:v7.4=, jacobalberty/unifi:v7.4.162=, jacobalberty/unifi:v7.4=, jacobalberty/unifi:v7=, org.opencontainers.image.ref.name=ubuntu, org.opencontainers.image.version=18.04)
Sep 30 13:15:07 lserver systemd[1]: aca8a5a216ea6cdacc27cac48aa7ba8da880534d7bd332b626a5a3cef7e85c57.service: Deactivated successfully.
```